# Django ORM get related sets through foreign keys along 2 related paths

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I'm working on a system that has some complex relationships and I'm trying to find an efficient way to filter some data.

Suppose I have the following relationships:

`model C` - FK -> `model B` - FK -> `model A`

`model C` - FK -> `model R` - FK -> `model T` - FK -> `model Z`

Given an instance of `model A` how can I get all `Z`s associated with it?

One approach (that I think is working - but not very efficient) is as follows:

```
class A(models.Model):
    @property
    def get_related_Zs(self):
        Cs = models.C.objects.filter(B__A=self)
        Zs = models.Z.objects.filter(R__T__Z__in=Cs).distinct()
        return Zs
```

Perhaps this is the best approach (I doubt it).  Any ideas for a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is:

```
class A(models.Model):
    @property
    def get_related_Ts(self):
        Ts = T.objects.filter( R__C__B__A = self ).distinct()
        return Ts
```

**Explaining**: The easy way is to start by needed model, `T` in your case. Then, you can navigate to `A` through relations. django query api will translate it to SQL Joins for your database back-end.

**Notice**: Remember than model should be exist in database before execute sentence.

Comment: I didn't know the ORM was smart enough to know how to handle the 2 entries at C.  Thank you!